# R Simmer - "Number of keys and values don't match"

Tags: r, queue, queueing

I am trying to simulate a JSQ(d) (join-shortest-queue of d sampled queues) system but am having trouble executing my code. In this case, let us assume d=2. I wish to have job size determined upon arrival (the value of "X") as well as the selection of which 2 queues will be sampled and "JSQ-ed" (this could be done perhaps differently, though for my purposes beyond this minimal working example, these must be determined upon arrival).

```
library(simmer)
set.seed(1337)

sim <- simmer("sim")

queues <- vector(length=1000)
for (i in 1:1000) {
  queues[i] <- paste0("q_",i)
}

queueing_system <- trajectory() %>%
  set_attribute("X", function() rexp(1)) %>%
  set_attribute("d", function() sample(1000,2)) %>%
  select(function() queues[get_attribute(sim, "d")], policy="shortest-queue") %>%
  seize_selected()%>%
  timeout(function() get_attribute(sim, "X")*(rpois(1, 1)+1)) %>%
  release_selected()


for (i in 1:1000) {
  sim %>%
    add_resource(queues[i], 1)
}
sim %>%
  add_generator("path", queueing_system, function() rexp(1,1)) %>%
  run(400) %>%
  now()
```

I receive

```
Error: 'path0' at 0.15 in [SetAttribute]->SetAttribute->[Select]:
 number of keys and values don't match
```

What seems to be the issue and how might I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes store a single value. Why don't you sample directly in the `select` activity? I.e.,

```r
queueing_system <- trajectory() %>%
  set_attribute("X", function() rexp(1)) %>%
  select(function() queues[sample(1000, 2)], policy="shortest-queue") %>%
  seize_selected()%>%
  timeout(function() get_attribute(sim, "X")*(rpois(1, 1)+1)) %>%
  release_selected()
```

I would call `rexp(1)` in place too, instead of defining `X`.

Comment: This is a minimal working example of my true issue - by the constraints of my larger problem, I am unable to sample within select (the value of "d" will be used in another part of my simulation and thus need it stored). So, to be clear, I cannot store more than one attribute per arrival? If that is so, I can try vectorizng values.

Comment: You can store as many attributes as you want, but each attribute must be a single value. Vectors are not supported.

Comment: How, then, would I store the values of X and d in this particular case?

Comment: You can use more attributes, e.g., `set_attribute(paste0("d", 1:2), function() sample(1000,2))`.

Comment: That seems to make sense, though it is clear I am selecting it wrongly after setting it: `queueing_system <- trajectory() %>%
  set_attribute("X", function() rexp(1,100)) %>%
  set_attribute(paste0("d", 1:2), function() sample(1000,2)) %>%
  select(queues[c(function()get_attribute("d1"),function()get_attribute("d2"))], policy="shortest-queue") %>%
  seize_selected()%>%
  timeout(function() get_attribute(sim, "X")*(rpois(1, 10)+1)) %>%
  release_selected()`

Comment: Nevermind, I believe I got it:  `queueing_system <- trajectory() %>% set_attribute("X", function() rexp(1,100)) %>% set_attribute(paste0("d", 1:2), function() sample(1000,2)) %>% select(function()queues[c(get_attribute(sim,"d1"),get_attribute(sim,"d2"))], policy="shortest-queue") %>% seize_selected()%>% timeout(function() get_attribute(sim, "X")*(rpois(1, 10)+1)) %>% release_selected()`

Comment: Easier: `get_attribute(sim, paste0("d", 1:2))`.